# Trying to add multiple views that are aligned horizontally while dynamically adding the same view vertically

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

So my program has info about restaurants (logo, Name, and phone number) and I want those to be aligned horizontally, but I want to be able to add more of those views upon the user's request. I'm currently using LinearLayout with the orientation set to Vertical. I was wondering if there was any way to align them horizontally while adding additional views with the same info below (being an ImageView, and 2 text views). And if so what the code would look like. My XML code currently looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/First"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the code looks like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG="MAIN";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG,"STAERTED");
        ImageView firstImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.First);
        int imageResource=getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/italian",null,this.getPackageName());
        firstImage.setImageResource(imageResource);

    }
}
```

Comment: as your problem is on UI, it would be so much better for us if you could upload 2 pictures, one with what you would like to have, and one with what you actually have, so we can help you and understand where the problem is.

Comment: first of all you should use horizontal recyclerview. through this it will be easy for you to add same layout in your horizontal list and u can easily arrange them horizontally

Comment: @David so you want to add logo and two field dynamically ,one below another. am i right?